# Why is there more details available in Powershell than REST API for Exchange Online Servers, Azure Active Directory and other are present in cloud

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, exchange-server, office365api

I have been going through the API documentation and though there is a lot of APIs available it is not quite comparable to the details provided through PowerShell. Since these features exist in the cloud it is much easier to develop endpoints rather than cmdlets. Am I missing something and is there a way to access all the information extensively through API itself or do cmdlets still have higher details

If I am working on Cloud solution, lets say Azure AD or Exchange Online then why is it that I have to use Powershell to get all the information. Since it is in cloud shouldn't Graph API be available for everything (Since powershell will also download using some sort of http protocol). Why cant Microsoft expose this.

Answer (score 0):

It takes engineering time to build new APIs. The exchange powershell interface has existed for almost 10 years. That is an immense amount of time to build a lot of functionality. It will take a lot of time to rationalize and redo that work in Graph.